# How are logical expressions that include increment and decrement operators evaluated in C?

Tags: c, logical-operators, logical-or, logical-and

```
int a = 0, b= 1, c = 1;
if (c-- || ++a && b--)
```

I know that the precedence for && is the highest here. So what happens? Does it start from && and then looks at the expression on its left which is (c-- || ++a) and evaluates that first?

I have been experimenting for a while with different expressions and I just can't wrap my head around it. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I would have used parenthesis if I could but this is a uni question so I don't really have a say

Comment: Don't try to wrap your head around those precedence / grammar rules: **use parenthesis** ==> `if ((c-- || ++a) && b--)` or `if (c-- || (++a && b--))` ... even better if you remove the `++` and `--` from the expression.

Comment: @pmg yeah but uni questions don't really come with parenthesis sooo..

Comment: Even better - don't cram all those pre- and post-increment operators into that one line of code.  That code will fail most code reviews because it's more complex than necessary, and therefore harder to read and maintain **for no good reason**.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It's a homework assignment, they don't get to choose the style.

Comment: Ah! well ... then have a talk with your teacher and tell her to see this question :)

Comment: Usually, uni questions expect you to answer them, not for you to ask someone else to answer it for you. (Check your school's academic honesty policy for how outside assistance should be credited.)

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, deciphering crap code is an important skill.  But so is recognizing it.  Even better is learning how to avoid it.  Were I teaching a C class, I'd accept as the most correct answer, "Go sit in front of the monitor on the desk of the programmer who wrote that until I get a complete explanation of what it does along with a revised, readable version - and not leave until I do."

Comment: @RaymondChen fair but this question is from last years test. So this question is purely for educational purposes

Comment: @AndrewHenle It looks like they're trying to use this to teach the distinction between operator precedence and short-circuiting. It will be hard to come up with a real-world piece of code that demonstrates it.

Comment: So beware of putting side-effects into conditonal statements, because short-circuit evaluation says they may or may not be executed.

Comment: @WeatherVane Short-circuiting is often depended on in conditional statements. `if (y != 0 && x / y > 1)` to prevent division by 0. That's why it's important to learn how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operator precedence does not totally determine evaluation order.  What it does do is dictate how operands are grouped.  And since `&&` has higher precedence than `||` as you noted, your expression is equivalent to:

```
(c-- || (++a && b--))
```

Given that the `&&` operator uses short circuit evaluation, `++a` would be evaluated before `++b`.  However, the entire subexpression `++a && b--` is the right side of the `||` operator which also uses short circuit evaluation, which means the left side, i.e. `c--` would get evaluated first.

Since `c--` evaluates to 1, the right side of the `||` operator, i.e. `++a && b--`, is not evaluated.  So `c` gets decremented and `a` and `b` are left unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

Because of operator precedence, this is equivalent to

```
if (c-- || (++a && b--))
```

Logical operators are processed left-to-right with short-circuiting. So this first performs `c--`. This decrements `c` to `0`, but because it's post-decrement the value is its original value `1`. This is truthy, so the `||` operator immediately evaluates to `1` without evaluating its right hand operand.

So the condition is true, but only `c` is modified.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the precedence for && is the highest here.

Well... no. The precedence for the `--` postfix operators is the highest, second highest is the prefix `++`, then `&&`, then `||`.

Operator precedence/associativity is only relevant for determining which operands that "glue" to which operator. In this case operator precedence makes the expression equivalent to `(c--) || ((++a) && (b--))`.

From there on we can forget about operator precedence and instead worry about *order of evaluation*. Normally, operators in C do not specify a an order of evaluation of the operands. Logical AND and OR are exceptions here, explicitly stating a defined order of evaluation (C17 6.5.13):

> Unlike the bitwise binary `&` operator, the `&&` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second operands. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.

Similar text also exists for `||`. These special evaluation rules are often referred to as "short circuit evaluation", which is a rather unhelpful analogy (details: [What is the meaning of "short circuit" operators?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/289828))

All of this means that the compiler has to build up an internal expression parser tree where the sub expressions inside `++a && b--` will only get evaluated if that whole expression will get evaluated, which in turn depends on the outcome of the evaluation of `(c--)`.

So the compiler *must* evaluate the expression as:

- Evaluate `c--`, if `1` then the result is 1, stop evaluation. The `c--` is then executed.
- Otherwise, evaluate and execute `++a`. If `0`, then the result is 0, stop evaluation. The `c--` is then executed.
- Otherwise, evaluate `b--`. If '1', then the result is 1, otherwise 0. `c--` and `b--` are then executed.